# Why routerLink and putting url on browser works and navigate of angular does not working?

Tags: angular

I am studying angular and I have a problem with route, more specifically with Navigate.
I have these routes in my RouterModule:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: "", redirectTo: '/phrases', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: "phrases", component: PhrasesComponent, children: [
    { path: "new", component: EditPhraseComponent },
    { path: ":id", component: PhraseDetailComponent },
    { path: ":id/edit", component: EditPhraseComponent },
  ]},
  { path: "about", component: AboutComponent },
  { path: "**", component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true })
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

If I try access typing on the browser or by routerLink works, like this image but in my Navigate does not work.

[image]

My navigate:

```
  editPhrase() {
    console.log(this.router)
    this.router.navigate([1, "/edit"], {relativeTo: this.route});
  }
```

Looks like right for me, I don't know what is wrong.

If I try access typing on the browser or by routerLink works, I think my router module is perfect and how works with routerLink, I expected that using on the same way with navigate should works

Comment: Please include your code as text, not as a linked image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reverse line 16 with line 17 in your first image for the pattern matching to works.

Comment: Thanks. I tried but don't work.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem. In my template had this code:

```
 <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-end gap-3">
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="editPhrase()">Edit</a>
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Detail</a>
 </div>
```

I changed to this:

```
  <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-end gap-3">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" (click)="editPhrase()">Edit</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary">Detail</a>
  </div>
```

I did not realized the "href" before.

Thanks everybody for help.